# improve insertion time in cassandra database with datastax cpp driver

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax

I have a simple table that I am populating using the datastax cpp driver. The table is stored in a cassandra database. The table is created like this:

```
create table data (
    dt_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    dt_numbers list<int>,
    insertion_time timestamp,
)
```

So, for every row I am inserting

```
VALUES (1, [1,2,3,4], now())
```

The problem is that I tried to insert 1 million rowσ and the time was 35 minutes. That time is considered high in a production environment.

Some pseudocode:

```
std::map<int, vector<int>> myData;
for( all entries in myData) {
  const char* query = "INSERT INTO...";
  future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
  cass_future_wait(future);
}
```

The data are stored in an std::map and I don't care which map index will be written first, but every map entry should be inserted exactly one. Is there any way to enhance the performance of this program? Is there an example?

The code I am using so far is to write one row after the other and is similar with the code used in one of the datastax examples

```
    CassError insert_into_basic(CassSession* session, const char* key, const Basic* basic) {
      CassError rc = CASS_OK;
      CassStatement* statement = NULL;
      CassFuture* future = NULL;
      const char* query = "INSERT INTO examples.basic (key, bln, flt, dbl, i32, i64) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";

      statement = cass_statement_new(query, 6);

      cass_statement_bind_string(statement, 0, key);
      cass_statement_bind_bool(statement, 1, basic->bln);
      cass_statement_bind_float(statement, 2, basic->flt);
      cass_statement_bind_double(statement, 3, basic->dbl);
      cass_statement_bind_int32(statement, 4, basic->i32);
      cass_statement_bind_int64(statement, 5, basic->i64);

      future = cass_session_execute(session, statement);
      cass_future_wait(future);

      rc = cass_future_error_code(future);
      if (rc != CASS_OK) {
        print_error(future);
      }

      cass_future_free(future);
      cass_statement_free(statement);

      return rc;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting slow performance because you are writing one row at time AND waiting for that single row to be really written to. If you look carefully at docs, you'll find that to get the best of performance from C* you really need to perform asynchronous writes. In pseudo code it would be something like:

```
std::map<int, vector<int>> myData;
std::list<CassFuture> futures;
for( all entries in myData) {
  const char* query = "INSERT INTO...";
  futures.push_back(cass_session_execute(session, statement));
  if (futures.size() > 5000) {
    for (all entries in futures) {
       cass_future_wait(future);
       cass_future_free(future);
    }
    futures.clear();
  }
}
// Wait for the "trailing" futures... 
for (all entries in futures) {
   cass_future_wait(future);
   cass_future_free(future);
}
```

That way you should get a performance boost. You should need to tune that `5000` to match your requirements/hardware specs. And, of course, implement some strategy to handle write failures.